# How to take care of fop font cache folder , which is throwing exception

Tags: maven, pdf, xslt, aem, apache-fop

For PDF generation in AEM, I am using combination of apache fop API + XSL:fo + OOTB AEM transformer

The issue is that I am facing this error

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Deserialization not allowed for class org.apache.fop.fonts.FontCache

It comes because of which PDF generated are not opening and gives 500.

I resolved the issue locally by deleting ".fop folder (which contained fop-fonts.cache document) which is created parallel to .m2 . Once I deleted this folder and did the maven build, I was able to view PDFs properly and the exception not came again.

But this issue is also coming to QA and other servers and intermittently in my local. So can anyone suggest what may be the permanent solution for it or any helping inputs for above error?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, .fop directory needs to be deleted when referenced fonts fail to load. FOP is forced to re-parse all the fonts when this happens and since it's a bit intermittent across environments (as per your question), I would assume that some referenced fonts are missing.

You can try one of the following approaches:

- Install fonts as part of your environment build (least preferred option).
- Fix font references in case you are using wildcards (like .*) to to bind to existing common fonts. (May ruin styling but will be mostly compatible)
- Embed fonts. (Increase document size)
- Substitute fonts. (Again, this might degrade styling)

I would recommend picking a suitable option from above based around your PDF distribution scope.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But already fonts are the part of my codebase under /etc/clientlibs. Still, I am getting this error. Any other pointer or help for me to resolve java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
Deserialization not allowed for class org.apache.fop.fonts.FontCache error. I am still facing it

Comment: Can you post any compilation logs? The fonts must be resolved at compilation otherwise you will see some warning like 'fount not found, substituted' If you are not seeing any warnings then at least a valid binding info must be there. Try using maven with -X switch

Comment: While compiling using -X , I am not getting any error in logs related to fonts . [INFO] Deleting file /Users/user/Desktop/project/content/target/classes/etc/clientlibs/project/global/fonts/univers/UniversLTStd.woff

[DEBUG] copy /Users/user/Desktop/project/content/src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/clientlibs/project/global/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot to /Users/user/Desktop/project/content/target/classes/etc/clientlibs/project/global/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot